# ClickOnce with .NET Core - What is the exact (invisible) msbuild command of the "Publish" button?

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, azure-pipelines, clickonce

I want to create a ClickOnce setup from .NET Core 3.1 applications (console and desktop app) and deploy it by an Azure Build Pipeline.

The "core way" of Visual Studio is to create a ClickOnce settings file (`ClickOnceProfile.pubxml`) and then to click the "Publish" button.

[image]

This works fine and as result I get the files `setup.exe`, `myApp.application`, `Publish.html` and the directory `Application Files` with a subdirectory full of `*.deploy` files.

[image]

Unfortunately I couldn't figure out, **how to get the same result by a command-line call**. Even after many hours of reading articles, StackOverflow, etc. and many tries on local command-line (`msbuild`) and inside of the Azure build pipeline (`vsbuild` with `msbuildArgs` as params). Also I didn't find a logfile with the executed command call.

The Microsoft article [Build .NET ClickOnce applications from the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/building-dotnet-clickonce-applications-from-the-command-line?view=vs-2022) is specific for .NET Core 3.1 and newer. It says it's done easily like this call:

```
msbuild /target:publish /p:PublishProfile=<pubxml file> /p:PublishDir="<specific location>"
```

I only could get a half correct result, which is a mixture of the wanted files and several unwanted files. It seems to be that the pure binary output (e.g. from `bin\debug`) is always added to the defined `PublishDir`.
I suppose the settings of `ClickOnceProfile.pubxml` are not the problem, because the publish button uses it, too.

So the *one billion dollar question* is: **Which exact command-line call is done by Visual Studio when clicking the `Publish` button.** (or maybe multiple calls?)